# Why gaussian mixture model is sensitive to cluster size?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I did an experiment where I generated 3 well separated clusters with a different multivariate gaussian distribution for each cluster. One of the clusters contains 1000 points and the other two clusters contain 100 points each.
It is pretty obvious in K-means that it does not work well in this setting as we minimize the SSE and centroids tends to go for dense regions. However, I don't understand why the Gaussian mixture model does not behave well (it identifies 3 clusters in the big cluster with 1000 points). So as the size of one clusters gets very large compared to the other clusters, GMM does not identify the right clusters and tries to divide the cluster with the biggest number of observations.

Comment: Could you clarify the last sentence, especially "... does not behave well and identify bad clusters as the size of one clusters gets very large..."?  I *think* I know what you mean, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, I changed a bit the formulation, hope that helps

Comment: Yes, that made it clear to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment to figure out what happens when you run a GMM algorithm.

At the beginning, you will need to find  starting point (initial centroid) for each cluster. This might be guessed or extracted from a KMeans clustering. If one sample is very large, the initial centroids of the minor clusters will likely be in the scatter of the big ones.

Now, an iterative expectation maximization algorithm starts it work.

First, the likelihood is calculcated for each data point (a matrix with n (number of datapoints) rows and d (number of clusters) columns.

The first value of the likelihood matrix is the probability that point 1 was produced by the Gaussian that represents cluster 1. The first row of this matrix does not sum to one, since the probabilities are calculated for each Gaussian independently. The maximum value of the first row is in the column of the Gaussian that is "closest" to the datapoint.

Then, the responsibilities are calculated by multiplying the likelihood matrix with the prior information and dividing by the row's sum. The prior information is given in the form of relative cluster sizes, e.g. 90% for the big, and 10% for the small). The first value of this (n, d) shaped matrix tells you the probability that the first point is from distribution 1 (rather than distribution 2), these rows sum to one. In your scenario, you have one big prior (your major cluster).

It is rational to use this prior information. If I know that it never rains in the desert, it is sensible to take this as the best guess and to "ignore" my observation of clouds due to my prior knowledge that it simply never rains.

This is what is likely to happen: Your big cluster overlaps with the centroid of the smaller one. The smaller one has to be very close to a datapoint in order to "own" it, since the prior information acts as a handycap for the small cluster. This makes it very hard for the centroid to move through the "space" to reach the correct position, since positions are updated by the sum of all datapoints weighted by their responsibilties.

From my experience: If you provide good initial starting values by manual annotation or expert guess, you will be able to fit GMM even for unbalanced cluster sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I thought exaclty about this and set the initial positions randomly in the space (not the data points) and I obtained bad results from gmm for 20 different runs

Comment: I don't understand this part 'The prior information is given in the form of relative cluster sizes, e.g. 90% for the big, and 10% for the small)'. In the case where initial centroids are assigned randomly in the space, actually the prior is close to flat and still from my experiments it doesn't change much :/

Comment: The prior isn't on the initial centroids, it's on the cluster membership of each point.

Comment: thank you so much got it